# npm run gulp with parameters

Tags: node.js, npm

I've started learning gulp and I'm dealing with a small issue.
I have the following file:

```
//Test gulp file 
var gulp = require("gulp"), 
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify"); 

//Scripts task 
//Uglifies 
gulp.task("scripts", function(){ 
    console.log("run scripts"); 
    gulp.src("public/src/js/home/app.js")
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("public/src/js/home/bundle"));  //Use *.js to uglify all 
}); 

gulp.task("default", []);
```

When trying to execute the file using:

```
npm run gulp scripts
```

It does not execute the assigned task.
However, when I add it to the parameters of the default:

```
gulp.task("default", ["scripts"]);
```

It does work when I run

```
npm run gulp
```

I installed gulp locally in my project folder.
Any reason why passing the "scripts" parameter doesn't work?

Comment: which version of npm ?

Comment: @PierreInglebert It's 1.4.28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only npm >= 2 pass arguments to scripts, it's a part of the new features as you can see in "why 2.0.0?" part [here](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/98131109725/npm200)